# Gig interface in vMX

Tags: juniper-mx

can you please help me on how to convert the em interface to gig interface in the vMX, i am trying to assign interface to vrf and the em is not support.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Juniper vMX is not all that easy to set up properly. Check the [documentation](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/vmx17.2/topics/task/installation/vmx-installing-ova.html) for a proper installation guide.

### Architecture

The main thing to remember is that the vMX is actually two VMs that you need to connect with each other: the Routing Engine (virtual control plane - VCP) and the Packet Forwarding Engine (virtual forwarding plane - VFP). The architecture looks like this (from the [Juniper site](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/vmx17.2/topics/concept/vmx-architecture.html)):

[image: Architecture of a vMX Instance]

The **VCP** has two interfaces:

- the first interface (fxp0) is the management interface. You'll probably manage the vMX through the IP-address on this interface.
- the second interface (em1) connects to the VFP VM.

The **VFP** can have more interfaces:

- the first interface is a management interface (which you probably won't need).
- the second interface connects to the VCP VM.
- any further interfaces (maximum 8 under VMware) are ge-0/0/x interfaces, starting numbering at ge-0/0/0 for the third interface.

### Troubleshooting

If your ge- interfaces aren't working, then the communication between the VCP and the VFP VMs is probably the problem.

When everything's good, the ge- interfaces should show up when you do a **show interfaces**:

```
show interfaces terse | match ge-
```

If the interfaces don't show, then you need to troubleshoot the VCP-VFP connection:

1. wait long enough for the VFP to boot properly (takes longer than the VCP).
2. try to ping the VFP from the VCP to verify :

   `ping 128.0.0.16 routing-instance __juniper_private1__`
3. Try the troubleshooting steps from the [Juniper site](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/vmx17.2/topics/task/verification/vmx-vm-connection-troubleshooting-esxi.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should have 3rd HDD that needs to be added to the VCP VM - metadata_usb.vmdk

[image]